# How to avoid endless render loop in React while updating Parent Accordion height?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion

Hi everyone and thanks for reading. I have a big problem in React with a nested Accordion. In fact when the child Accordion opens, the parent Accordion was not updating.

```
interface AccordionProps {
  title?: string;
  subtitle?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  isOpened?: boolean;
  topChildren?: React.ReactNode;
  bottomChildren?: React.ReactNode;
  onToggle?: () => void;
}

function Accordion({
  title,
  subtitle,
  children,
  isOpened = false,
  topChildren,
  bottomChildren,
  onToggle,
}: AccordionProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(isOpened);
  const contentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [contentHeight, setContentHeight] = useState("0px");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (contentRef.current && contentRef.current.parentElement) {
      setContentHeight(open ? `${contentRef.current.scrollHeight}px` : "0px");
    }
    if (onToggle) {
      onToggle();
    }
  }, [contentRef, open, children, onToggle]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.accordion}>
      <div className={styles.top} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        <div className={styles.left}>
          {topChildren || (
            <>
              <div className={styles.title}>{title}</div>
              <div className={styles.subtitle}>{subtitle}</div>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.right}>
          <img
            src={iconArrowDown}
            alt=""
            className={`${styles.arrowIcon} ${
              open ? styles.arrowIconRotated : ""
            }`}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        ref={contentRef}
        className={`${styles.content} ${open ? styles.open : ""}`}
        style={{
          maxHeight: contentHeight,
        }}
      >
        <div className={styles.overflow}>{children}</div>
        {bottomChildren && <div>{bottomChildren}</div>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Accordion;
```

HomePage

```
function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div>
     
        <ParentAccordion />
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;

function ParentAccordion() {
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(0);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setUpdate((prevUpdate) => prevUpdate + 1);
  };

  return (
    <Accordion title="Parent" onToggle={handleToggle}>
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
      <Accordion title="Child">
        <div
          style={{
            width: "300px",
            height: "300px",
            backgroundColor: "yellowgreen",
          }}
        >
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
        </div>
      </Accordion>
    </Accordion>
  );
}
```

Thank you very much, you save my life

So I passed a callBack`your text` function onToggle. To be able to determine the opening of the child Accordion and update the Parent. it works but i have a problem of endless rendering loop. I can't seem to keep the behavior that causes the height of the Parent to update when the child opens without getting the error:

Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.